# UIActivityViewController xcode warning

Tags: uiactivityviewcontroller

i got this message in debug area when i tap on my barButtomItem to share contents from my app to FB, Tw, Weibo and mail. iOs6 XCode 4.5.1

> 2013-03-08 15:59:31.609 cytology[2088:1cd03] Launch Services:
>   Registering unknown app identifier com.apple.mobilemail failed
>   2013-03-08 15:59:31.610 cytology[2088:1cd03] Launch Services: Unable
>   to find app identifier com.apple.mobilemail

this is my code:

```
-(IBAction)shareButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"shareButton pressed");

    NSString *texttoshare = _txt;
    UIImage *imagetoshare = _img;
    NSArray *activityItems = @[texttoshare, imagetoshare];    
    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact, UIActivityTypePrint];
    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:TRUE completion:nil];
}
```

despite the compile warning message i'm able to succesfully post and send mail... i read something about to use external libraries but i don't like this solution. i'm sure i miss something obvious.

any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From what I have read, there are problems with the social framework & the simulators. 
Have you tried on a **real device**?

or

maybe because the simulator has **no mail app**.

Comment: Most likely the problem is that the simulator doesn't have mail app. I will try on real device then i will post my results. Anyway this happen with the new share method's in ios6, if i use the old method  (mailservice) the warning doesnt appear, also i use to share with weibo, the sim. Does not have the weibo app installed but the warning there isn't…i will let you know my progress